# Attaching onclick=call_locker() event to a CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am trying to implement a content locker on my WP site. I would usually add the HTML code `onclick="call_locker()"` on the element that triggers the pop up. However, I do not have direct access to the HTML due to the plugin that I use for building the site.

This is the button element I want to attach the `call_locker()` function to:

```html
<a href="#" target="_self" class="fl-button" role="button">
    <span class="fl-button-text">Subscribe!</span>
</a>
```

My intention is to attach the `call_locker()` function to the whole `.fl-button` class via a `.onclick` triggered event. This way I will be able to use it globally on any other `.fl-button` or page that I create.

This is the code I came up with:

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("fl-button").onclick = function() { 
    call_locker(); 
  };
})();
```

However, nothing happens when I click on the button :-(

I am no expert on java so I can only hope my syntax is correct and the terms I used for the post too.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you don't have to be a java expert to write good JS (they are different langs)... Look into jQuery's delegated events, or find a tut on manual delegation patterns. In short, you bind to the root and pass a css selector that then filters raised events, dispatching them to the specific tags as-needed.

Comment: `.....me("fl-button")[0].onclick`

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns several html objects that you must iterate over and assign an event listener to

Comment: Simpler: `document.querySelector("a.fl-button").onclick=call_locker;`

Comment: None of them worked. With the first solution I get a **TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined**. There is just one element of such class on the page. @Pranav C Balan

Comment: With the second solution I get a **document.querySelector(...) is null** error. Besides, if I change the part `= function() {call_locker(); }` to `= call_locker();`, as you suggest the function is called directly as the page loads, disregarding any onclick condition. I am wondering if, given those errors, it is possible that this code is somehow being loaded before any element in the page is rendered. Can that be possible? @mplungjan

Comment: I did not have () on my call - look again `document.querySelector("a.fl-button").onclick=call_locker;`

Comment: @PabloGonzález : move your code to end of the page.... and make sure that the element is loaded when script is executing..

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), wich is an array like object. You need to iterate over the object and add your `click` event listener for each anchor tag.

> [**Document.getElementsByClassName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
>
> *Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names...*

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over the collection, but before you have to convert it an array, which can be done by calling `[].slice.call(HTMLCollection)`.

Here is an example.

```js
var flBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("fl-button");

[].slice.call(flBtns).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    // call your locker function here.
    //call_locker()
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fl-button">FL Button 1</a>
<a href="#" class="fl-button">FL Button 2</a>
<a href="#" class="fl-button">FL Button 3</a>
<a href="#" class="fl-button">FL Button 4</a>
```